# Specflow calling step from step definition throws TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Container of the steps class has not been initialized

Tags: c#, specflow

I am trying to call a step from a step definition, but I get a `SpecFlowException` when I do that.

Look at the following example:

```
[Binding]
public class MySteps: Steps 
{
    [Given("Doing some actions, getting (.*)  and (.*)")]
    public void DoingSomeActionsGettingValueAndOtherValue(int a, int b)
    {
        Given($"I pass first integer {a} and second integer {b}");
    }

    [Given(@"I pass first integer (.*) and second integer (.*)")]
    public void ThenIPassFirstIntegerValueAndSecondIntegerValue(int a, int b)
    {
        AreEqual(a, b);
    }
}
```

The exception is the following:

```
-> error: Container of the steps class has not been initialized!
TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Container of the steps class has not been initialized!
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps.AssertInitialized()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps.get_TestRunner()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps.Given(String step)
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this particular error and how do I fix it? I couldn't find much help on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error in a new project, but it succeeds for me.

My specflow class is copied from yours:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    [Binding]
    public class MySteps : Steps
    {
        [Given("Doing some actions, getting (.*)  and (.*)")]
        public void DoingSomeActionsGettingValueAndOtherValue(int a, int b)
        {
            Given($"I pass first integer {a} and second integer {b}");
        }

        [Given(@"I pass first integer (.*) and second integer (.*)")]
        public void ThenIPassFirstIntegerValueAndSecondIntegerValue(int a, int b)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the feature file:

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature1
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
    As a math idiot
    I want to be told the sum of two numbers

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given Doing some actions, getting 1  and 1
```

My advice is to try to reproduce the error as well in a new project, and if it succeeds there, the bug must be hiding in code you haven't posted in your question.